# How to create multi pods to run test case in bash scrips

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

we have many test cases and want run one case(need execute multi command to run the test) in one pod. for example, we have 1000 cases, and we want to create 1000 pods in bash scripts with pod yaml template. is there any easy way to start/monitor/terminate the pods ?

current i just use the jenkins pipeline to get the pod and run the test in parallel. i just want to try use bash scripts to manage the flow but not sure what is the best way.

Comment: The manner in question is asked is very theoretical and lacks supporting examples. Consider, rephrasing and adding more information

Comment: @FrankXie from the `POD`  in your context, I assume that you have Kubernetes environment.

If this is the case I'd suggest using Kubernetes native `Cronjob` s for each test.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cronjob